# Timer in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a UpdatePanel control in which there is a ListView that would read some data from a SQL Server.I want to use a Timer to periodic update this ListView every 1 or 2 minutes.
What should I do in the Tick Event to do the partial refresh in the UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the control inside the update panel that needs to be refreshed. Take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx).

Comment: I have already read this example, but I still has a question. Because the control in the UpdatePanel is not Label, it's a ListView. You means that I need do ListView.DataBind? Is it right?